# Why doesn't PHP need a middle tier, where as other languages do

Tags: c#, java, php, middleware

For web based applications, why doesn't PHP need middleware to run - yet languages like Java, C#, etc do?

**UPDATE**:

Re-worded:  Why doesn't PHP need a middle tier, or business layer separating it from the database, whereas the others do.

Comment: What do you mean by "middleware"?

Comment: By "middleware" do you mean "virtual machine"?

Comment: I know what middleware is, yet the question still doesn't sense.

Comment: Please *name* a specific middleware a Java or C# application requires that PHP doesn't.

Comment: I think the OP is asking the question "Why doesn't PHP need a middle tier, or business later separating it from the database, whereas the others do". This is a fair question - if misguided. Rather than closing it, I think I'd rather have seen the misconception tackled.

Comment: "services to software applications beyond those available from the operating system" - if you define this as such, `PHP` also requires middleware, a php interpreter (either php command-line interpreter, or a web server module) to be able to execute. OS cannot execute php code by itself.

Comment: And the typical PHP app runs on Apache... your point being? :)

Comment: @RobLevine, what you said is exactly what I'm asking

Comment: @nickb `java` can run outside of Tomcat etc. `PHP` needs Apache (or other web server) to be used in a web application.

Comment: @nickb - you're showing a couple of "re-open" votes. With two more, the question will re-opened....

Comment: @nickb I'm still confused. Tomcat, Weblogic and Websphere don't provide middle tiers / business layers. You can write ASP.NET or JSP applications where the pages talk directly to the database without any further code.

Comment: @nickb if you're talking about **database** access, PHP still needs a driver (or module) to connect to any given kind of database (mysql/postgres/mssql/oracle/etc). Its just that quite a lot of those drivers are supplied with php distribution.

Comment: @RobLevine, thanks. I was/a surprised at how quickly my question turned negative by the SO community. Thank you for being the only positive voice in this thread.

Comment: @nickb That's what I thought you were asking - until you mentioned Tomcat. I haven't down-voted you, but it wasn't clear what you actually wanted to know, or why you think Java and C# need these extra  layers.

Comment: Please also do not confuse a *language* like PHP or C# with a whole *stack* or *framework* like .NET. Typically C# is used in connection with the whole shebang of .NET tuned for web apps and including the kitchen sink. You don't *have* to use C# with all of that. Conversely, you have that whole ecosystem available for PHP, but you need to piecemeal it together. I still don't know what kind of "business layer middleware" you're talking about.

Comment: @nickb - sometimes people are too quick to close questions. Personally, I'd rather see enough time given for people to re-write and clarify their questions rather than the immediate stamp-down that appeared to happen here. It doesn't always happen - maybe it's because its Friday!

Comment: Damn, it looks like I need a new username that is as ultra-creative as this one. Side note, what's going to happen now when somebody notifies @nickb ?!

Comment: @nickb I don't know, let's find out? :)

Comment: @nickb, what's interesting is that even though you're way more active on SO than me - I created my account a good year before you. -This message is also to test my own curiosity on how SO will handle two people with the same user name messaging each other back-and-forth

Comment: Aha. That explains why I was almost sure nickb had more than 400 rep at some point.

Comment: Damn - that's confusing.

Comment: @Rob It's reopened now, I'd like to see you tackle that misconception. :)

Comment: RobLevine & deceze, me too obviously :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by the term "middleware" you mean "a middle tier", or "a business layer" the answer is that none of them *need* it.

For example, there is nothing to stop you in C# (or more correctly, on the .Net Framework "stack") from writing code in web pages that directly accesses the database. Indeed, lots of prototypes start out this way.

The issue here is more around good practice - it is generally considered A Bad Thing(tm) to write web pages (sticking with the same example) that directly access the database and the reasons for this are many. Testability, security, good decoupled code - all these require you to separate your code out, and having several tiers is a natural way to do this.

Why do you not see as much of this with PHP? I think [Jeff's latest blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/06/the-php-singularity.html) covers this well :)

I'd go as far as to say that C# (the language), .Net (the Framework), ASP.NET (especially ASP.NET MVC) and much of the documentation and tutorials encourage you to do the right thing and not punch a whole from the web page through to the database.

But there isn't actually anything stopping you from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The use case that can appear is the following:

You have multiple web apps serving data that is stored in a database.  Let's say the web apps are:

1. Front-end for your desktop web experience
2. Front-end for your mobile web experience
3. Front-end for your APIs that you expose to developers

Let's say each front-end accesses the database directly.  *Then*, your eng team decides that the current database should be replaced.  Now you have the problem of rewriting code in *every* front-end.

If you had a middle tier to abstract the actual data store, you'd only re-write one layer of code.  Additionally, having unit tests for that middle tier would ensure that the way the middle tier exposes data remains uniform, regardless of the data storage platform.